# How to create sites taking values from database

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, object-model, database

In one interview, interviewer asked this question.
I have one table in sql server database which contains the Title and its id(int). 
Now I want to retrieve those values from database and based on the title, I have to create sites under one root website. How many values are there, that many sites needs to be create.

```
    Title                    ID  
-----------------------------------  
    A                        1
    B                        2
    C                        3
```

These are the values. Now I want to creata these three sites at a time. How to achieve it and if I change title of the site then it should update in the database as well. 
Any suggestions please

Answer (score 2):

This should not be hard, here is pseudocode:

```
Connect to this database and retrieve all the rows in this table
Connect to the desired SharePoint Site Collection (SPSite)

Foreach row in rows
       Add a web site under SPSite.RootWeb.Webs using Add method
```

For more details check [SPSite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.aspx), [SPWeb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.aspx), [SPWebCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms465759) objects and [SPWebCollection.Add methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms196970).

Comment: What about the update method. When we update the title of a site it should reflect in the database

Comment: Unfortunately SharePoint only has event handler that fires when an SPWeb object is created, there is no onupdate event. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebeventreceiver_members. You would have to build some scheduled check that iterates SPSite.AllWebs collection and checks if changes were made.

Answer (score 0):

1. One other alternative would be to create a BDC Entity out of your Table with SharePoint Designer, then from the newly External List have a new Workflow again via SharePoint Designer to start on item Creation and create a site automatically based on details. On update (ONLY via SharePoint list), use "Wait for a field change" activity you could update respective site. Both Create/Update site would rely on a custom Workflow Activity which is the only piece of code the would create/update site.
2. Or directly from within your SQL Server (particularly if you have a single-server farm) rely on SQL Triggers to call .NET Managed procedures which could use SharePoint Client Side Managed Code to create/update sites. - more complex honestly (security wise particularly).

Comment: I am not sure item 1. is an option. SharePoint workflows can't be triggered by External Lists. They can, once running from someplace else, read/write to external lists.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394479.aspx

"Workflows cannot be associated with an external list. In SharePoint Server 2010, although workflows work with external lists, they cannot be associated directly with external lists. You can create a site workflow, or have a list workflow on a SharePoint list, such as a document library, and have it read or update from an external list."

Comment: 1. Indeed you cannot direclty but ingenious alternatives allow to bridge that gap (more here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19418/how-do-i-associate-workflows-to-sharepoint-2010-external-lists)